# Arrow in the Arrow category

Tags: category-theory

> ## Arrow Categories:
>
> The Category $\text{Set}^{\to}$ of functions has as objects the set functions $f:A \to B$. An arrow in $\text{Set}^{\to}$ from the $\text{Set}^{\to}$ object $f:A \to B$ to the $\text{Set}^{\to}$ -object $g: C \to D$ is a pair of functions $\langle h, k \rangle$ such that $ g \circ h = k \circ f$
>
> Robert GoldBlatt- The Categorical Analysis of Logic, page-35

Could someone explain why the composition condition is important? I don't think I get the idea behind it.

Comment: Perhaps one reason is that it forms a commuting square.

Comment: Could you explain why that is important / significant here? I am new to cat theory @MichaelMorrow

Answer (score 2):

$\require{AMScd}$

All of these notions are more intuitive if you sketch diagrams. An arrow $\varphi$ in the category $\operatorname{Set}^\to$ from the object $f:A \to B$ to another object $g:C \to D$ should connect $f$ to $g$ *in a way that incorporates some of the structure from the original category* (where $f$ and $g$ are arrows). So $\varphi: f \to g$ in $\operatorname{Set}^\to$ more explicitly looks like
$$
\left(\;\;\begin{CD}
A \\
@V{f\,}VV \\
B
\end{CD}\right) 
\overset{\varphi}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\;\;\begin{CD}
C \\
@V{g\,}VV \\
D
\end{CD}\right) 
$$
where the vertical arrows are in $\operatorname{Set}$. The most natural way to construct this horizontal map $\varphi$ is to come up with arrows $h: A \to C$ and $k: B \to D$ in $\operatorname{Set}$. This forms the square
\begin{CD}
A @>{h}>> C \\
@V{f\,}VV @V{\llap{g\,}}VV \\
B @>{\smash{k}}>> D
\end{CD}
So in order for $\varphi = (h, k)$ to have anything to do with $f$ and $g$, we require that the square *commutes.* This is just another way to say that either way around the square is the same map $A \to D$ in $\operatorname{Set}$, i.e. $g \circ h = k \circ f$.

In order to familiarize yourself with this category $\operatorname{Set}^\to$, you should verify the axioms that arrows satisfy. (They all follow from the analogous properties in $\operatorname{Set}$.) For starters, how do you define composition? Draw diagrams!

Comment: I saw this question last night, but I didnt' get it but now that I see it again the first picture is one worth more than a 100 hundred words!

Comment: COuld you explain this part "in order for $\phi=(h,k)$ to have anything to do with $f$ and $g$, we require the square commutes" Could you explain it more specificall